# Adding a react component to a array in forEach does not render

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

EDIT: I have done some debugging and found that the elements I am adding to the display array are not being recognized. If I display the array in the console I can see that the size would be 2 for example, however If I display the length of array (display.length) it shows a length of 0.

I am trying to use firebase and react to create a little personal project. In this I am trying to get information from firebase and then display it. I am getting the data using a async function (basically copied the code from the firebase website to do it) so I guess that could possibly cause some issues but I am not smart enough to find a way to get information without it being async.

```
renderFavoriteGyms(){
    let display = []

    getGymsFromLocation("Rochester").then(ref =>{

        ref.map(gym => {
            display.push(<GymDisplay key ={gym} reference = {gym}/>)
        })
    })

    display.push(<GymDisplay  key = {"CRG Rochester"} 
    reference = {"Gyms/Rochester/CRG Rochester/Atributes"}/>)
    return display
}
```

When adding a react component inside of the forEach/map it does not render however manually pushing it worked perfectly. I manually checked in the dev console that the display array contains the correct information and it does. I am rendering below

```
render() {
    return(
        <div>

            <Row className='gymFavorites' sm = {4}>                      
                    <this.renderFavoriteGyms/>
            </Row>

        </div>
    )
}
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a function to render you can not call it as a component but as a function:

instead of:

```
<this.renderFavoriteGyms/>
```

do this:

```
{this.renderFavoriteGyms()}
```

Comment: I tried this, it is still not displaying. The dev tool says it has all the information I would expect. Could the issue instead be something  involving how I am getting the information? getGymsFromLocation is an async method, could that cause issues? I tested manually adding a react component to the display array and that would render, anything in the loop is the issue.